# List of deltas between ASP.NET 2.0 and ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a source for quickly getting up to speed with the general, programming deltas between ASP.NET 1.1/2.0 and ASP.NET 3.5? For example, I understand that cookies are no longer encouraged and you should use properties???

Is there a list out there somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"1.1 to 2.0" is rather different from "2.0 to 3.5"

This might help:
[An Overview of ASP.NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133927/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/112107-1.aspx)

Excerpt:

> Like with the progression from ASP.NET
>   2.0 to 3.0, the features in ASP.NET 3.5 are additive, meaning that the core assemblies installed from the
>   .NET Framework version 2.0 are still
>   used by the 3.0 and 3.5 versions. The
>   In short, ASP.NET 3.5 doesn't change
>   or take away or break any
>   functionality, concepts, or code
>   present in 2.0 - it simply adds new
>   types and features and capabilities to
>   the framework.

[image: Matrix]

Answer (score 1):

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133927/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/112107-1.aspx has a good summary that may be of help. It doesn't go into a ton of detail but is a good place to start.